# Using a custom WP_Query with get_template_part loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, get-template-part

I have a query for a custom post type:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$books = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'wiki',
    'posts_per_page' => '50',
    'paged' => $paged
));
?>
```

And i want to loop through these posts using the loop-books.php:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'books' ); ?>
```

Inside the loop-books.php i have these, just like the regular loop.php, i just changed the have_posts and the_post function to work with the $books query:

```
<?php if ( $books->have_posts() ) : ?>      
    <?php while ($books->have_posts()) : $books->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?><br/>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But after this, i get a php error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object in .../loop-books.php on line 1
```

So looks like the $books variable is not available inside the get_template_part function. How can i resolve this issue? If i put the $books query inside the loop-books.php its working fine, but i want to separate them.

Comment: try removing the `$books->` from loop-books.php & I hope it will work.

Comment: If i remove the $books-> part it will use a default query so thats not good for me.

Comment: if you are using something like:

`<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$books = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'wiki',
    'posts_per_page' => '50',
    'paged' => $paged
));
?>`
and here you load the `get_template_part` query.
And after this if you `reset postdata` then I think my solution will work properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will either need to globalize `$books` (if you want to stick to `get_template_part()` ) or use

```
require( locate_template( 'loop-books.php' ) );
```

instead of `get_template_part( 'loop', 'books' );`. This issue is caused by `$books` in `loop-books.php` being defined only in the [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of `get_template_part()`.

Comment: This. Though, if the `$books` query is specific to the `loop-books.php` template-part file, I would recommend just putting the `$books = new WP_Query()` call inside the template-part file.

Comment: Thanks. Whats your opinion, which one is the better solution?

Comment: Same, same @Chip - I'd also put it in the same file and avoid the issue in the first place. Answered this bearing in mind that the OP wanted to separate the two.

Comment: @passatgt As far as which is the better, see the above comments, I'd rather go with one file and be done with it. If you must separate them, I'd go with the `locate_template()` option, to not clutter the global namespace.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The reason i want to seperate them is because i want to use the same loop with other queries too based on other categories/taxonomies

Comment: Why not pass those other taxonomies as variables to your query arguments array? (How you do that would depend on specific context/implementation, but would certainly be cleaner than putting the entire query itself in a global.)

Answer (score 9):

An alternate method: open/close the loop, and then use `loop-books.php` to contain just the *markup* for the loop content. e.g.:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
// Get books query
$books = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'wiki',
    'posts_per_page' => '50',
    'paged' => $paged
));
// Open books loop
if ( $books->have_posts() ) :     
    while ($books->have_posts()) : $books->the_post();
        // Get loop markup
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'books' );
// Close books loop
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Then, inside of `loop-books.php`:

```
<?php the_title(); ?><br/>
```