# Which custom query am I in and how can I access its properties & methods?

Tags: wp-query, templates, query, get-template-part

Sometimes there's no way around creating a custom query, but when I do and then loop through it, I often want to use `get_template_part()` within the custom query loop to pull in a template I already know will fit my needs. Sometimes that template is 99.9% perfect and only needs some conditionals added for it to behave as needed depending on the query.

Assuming `is_main_query() = FALSE` in this template file, how can I (1) determine which query I *am* looping within; and (2) access the non-main query's properties and methods?

---

Example:

### **`page.php`**

```
<?php
  $two_posts        = new WP_Query(array(
    'nopaging'      => true,
    'post_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post__in'      => array(1, 2),
    'orderby'       => 'post__in'
  ));
?>

<?php if($two_posts->have_posts()) : ?>
  <div class="two-posts">
    <?php while($two_posts->have_posts()) : ?>
      <?php $two_posts->the_post(); ?>
      <?php get_template_part('templates/content', 'existing'); ?>
      <!-- or -->
      <?php include(locate_template('templates/content-existing.php')); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

### **`templates/content-existing.php`**

```
<?php if(is_main_query()) : ?>
  <p class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
<?php elseif(/* query == $two_posts */) : ?>
  <?php if(/* $two_posts->current_post == 0 */) : ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?><h1>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if(/* $two_posts->current_post == 1 */) : ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php else : ?>
  <p>Nothing to display here.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Related but not quite the same: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74064/using-a-custom-wp-query-with-get-template-part-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rarst's guidance I put together a quick solution that seems to do the trick even though it seems a bit hacky.

---

Solution:

### **`page.php`**

```
<?php
  $two_posts        = new WP_Query(array(
    'nopaging'      => true,
    'post_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post__in'      => array(1, 2),
    'orderby'       => 'post__in'
  ));

  /* Setup default global query boolean */
  $GLOBALS['two_posts_query'] = FALSE;

  /* Keep track of the post count */
  $GLOBALS['two_posts_count'] = $two_posts->post_count;
?>

<?php if($two_posts->have_posts()) : ?>
  <div class="two-posts">
    <?php while($two_posts->have_posts()) : ?>
      <?php $two_posts->the_post(); ?>
      <?php /* Keep track of the current post */ ?>
      <?php $GLOBALS['two_posts_current_post'] = $two_posts->current_post; ?>
      <?php /* Set global variable to TRUE */ ?>
      <?php $GLOBALS['two_posts_query'] = TRUE; ?>
      <?php get_template_part('templates/content', 'existing'); ?>
      <?php $GLOBALS['two_posts_query'] = FALSE; ?>
      <?php /* Reset global variable to FALSE */ ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

### **`templates/content-existing.php`**

```
<?php
  global $two_posts_query, $two_posts_post_count, $two_posts_current_post;
?>

<?php if($two_posts_query && $two_posts_post_count >= 2) : ?>
  <?php if($two_posts_current_post == 0) : ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?><h1>
  <?php elseif($two_posts_current_post > 0) : ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php else : ?>
  <p class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, **don't use `is_main_query()` function** (method is ok). It tells something absolutely different from what you would think it does — was the main query overridden.

As far as I remember, there is no clean solution to this since WP doesn't have a concept of explicitly passing context to a specific template or template part.

Since WP's way hinges primarily on globals, the “fitting” (if dirty) approach might be to pass the information in same fashion — through a global variable(s) of your own.