# Check for the main query from the template

Tags: wp-query, loop, get-template-part

Besides the main loop in index.php, I'm calling several other custom queries across the theme, like this:

```
$new_query = new WP_Query(array(
    // some args
));

if ($new_query->have_posts()) : 

    while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post();

        // This is the same template that I use in the main query or other custom queries
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content' );

    endwhile; 

endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Now I need to check from within the template file if it's being called from this custom query or from the main query.

So in content.php

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <?php if ( is_main_query() ) {
            // Do some staff
        } else {
            // Do other staff

        } ?>

</article>
```

`is_main_query()` is always returning true, since it's referring to `global $wp_query`, I suppose. I could use `$new_query->is_main_query()` but it's not possible from within the template file. So how this could be solved? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I found one solution here [Which custom query am I in and how can I access its properties & methods?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181111/which-custom-query-am-i-in-and-how-can-i-access-its-properties-methods)
The point is to set global boolean and check it in the template file

```
$new_query = new WP_Query(array(
    // some args
));

$GLOBALS['is_custom_query'] = FALSE;

if ($new_query->have_posts()) : 

    while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post();

        $GLOBALS['is_custom_query'] = TRUE;
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content' );
        $GLOBALS['is_custom_query'] = FALSE;

    endwhile; 

endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Not sure how reliable this solution is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`in_the_loop()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop), it returns true if we are in the main loop, false if we are not, like on a custom query loop

> Return: (bool) True if caller is within loop, false if loop hasn't started or ended.

The difference between [`is_main_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_main_query/) and `in_the_loop()` is that `is_main_query()` uses [`WP_Query::is_main_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_main_query/) which in turn uses the global `$wp_the_query`. `$wp_is_query` stores the main query, that is why `is_main_query()` always returns true inside the loop. You should also read [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/80454/31545)

So, in short, you can do

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <?php if ( in_the_loop() ) {
        // Do some staff
    } else {
        // Do other staff

    } ?>

</article>
```

Comment: Thanks Pieter. I actually tried `in_the_loop()`, but it returns true every time. Confusing.

Comment: Then there is some other issue on your page. It is working perfectly on my test install

Comment: I actually tried your code and only replaced `is_main_query()` with `in_the_loop()`. Try deactivating plugins, clear caches and switch to a bundled theme and retest

Comment: Doh, what a shame. Indeed, the mistake was on my part. I inserted this custom query right before `endwhile` of the main loop. Your answer is correct, thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you sorted it ;-). Enjoy